# How to fix high PCI adapter temperature?

Tags: 12.04, power-management, temperature

When running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, my Acer Aspire 4530 laptop and its PCI temperatures are around 70 degrees Celsius not even an exterior fan does anything about it. How can I make it run cooler?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to temperatures there are usually very few sensors in your computer - it'e either the CPU, the Hard Drive or the Motherboard (the chipset or, sometimes the video chip). A PCI is just the interface by which any of these components are connecting, so it could be either one of them. Try to intall a program called `sensors` to find out which one of them is causing the overheating - it will most likely be the CPU.

```
sudo apt-get install sensors
```

There are other programs that will allow you to scan and monitor the temperature of various components, but you have to figure out which part is causing the overheating - `xsensors`, `computertemp`, `fancontrol`, etc. - you can find them and install them from Ubuntu Software Center.

Some drivers can make your components run beyond their regular idle speed and cause overheating, but it could also be at the hardware level. Let me know when you find out.

Comment: Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +61.0°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +65.4°C  (high = +70.0°C)
this is what sensors gives me I have been using it for some time and this is my temperatures wile just browsing emails in Firefox if I start watching you tube or listen to music and stuff the temperatures go up to the 88 degrees and more in both of these readings the one that worries me the most is the second one because the first seems to be the CPU